# Remove extra space between content

Tags: jquery, html, css, pagination

[image]

There is a lots of extra space between two items  and  content and footer
I want it dynamically when the content is less in pagination there should be no space between items and content and footer.
when the data is more than it should push thwe pagination down and same with footer

here is the css

pagination.css

```
 ul.pagination{
margin-left:670px;
margin-top: 700px;


padding: 75px 0px 0px 0px;

overflow:hidden;
font:12px 'Tahoma';
list-style-type:none;   
}

ul.pagination li.details{
padding:7px 10px 7px 10px;
font-size:14px;
}

 ul.pagination li.dot{padding: 3px 0;}

 ul.pagination li{
float:left;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
margin-left:5px;
}

ul.pagination li:first-child{
margin-left:0px;
}

ul.pagination li a{
color:black;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
padding:7px 10px 7px 10px;
}

ul.pagination li a img{
border:none;
}
```

.item

```
      border-radius: 25px;
      padding: 20px;
     background-color:white;
    position: absolute;
    margin:10px;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:10px!important;
    width:  300px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    background: #ffff;
    font-size:20px !important;
    text-align:center;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
```

html

```
    <div id='masonry'>


      <?php 

        //show records
        $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");

        if($query === FALSE) { 
     die(mysqli_error($db)); // TODO: better error handling
                         }
        $count=1;

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $quote=$row['quote'];
            $name =$row['name'];

    ?>



      <div class="item">

     <?php echo "{$quote}";?><br>
      <?php echo "Author:- {$name}";?>


     </div>


    <?php 
    $count++;
    } 
    ?>

     </div>

   <script src='masonry.pkgd.min.js'></script>
    <script>
    var container = document.querySelector('#masonry');
var masonry = new Masonry(container, {
columnWidth: 50,
   itemSelector: '.item'
     });
     </script>

     <div id = "popular">
     <span> <h3> Popular Author </h3></span>


       <?php
      $query1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `author` WHERE popular = 1 ORDER BY `name` ASC LIMIT 35 ");
         if($query1 === FALSE) { 
        die(mysqli_error($db)); // TODO: better error handling
                            }
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)) {

            $name =$row['name'];
            $id   =$row['id'];

        ?>
    <div class="pop1">


     <a href="quotes.php?auth_id=<?php echo "$id";?>"><?php echo "$name";?></a>


    </div>


    <?php 
    $count++;
    } 
    ?>
    </br>
    <a href='popular_authors.php' class='button'>more popular author</a>

   </div>




  <?php echo pagination($statement,$limit,$page);?> 

  <div style="margin-top:0px"><?php include('footer.php');?></div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: i have inserted html

Comment: That doesn't help; it doesn't show the structure. You can't tell which of the things in the screenshot are caused by which HTML. You should shows the actual, generated HTML (as seen in the browser).

Comment: From this code not tell where is the issue. Fiddle/Code snippet of your issue and possible then post live link.

Comment: what should i do or what code you want....